# Draw multi-colored triangle with thick edges in opengl

Tags: opengl

[image]

Is it possible in opengl to draw this type to triangles?

I have already tried

- `glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);`
- `glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);`

Code and Result i got using `glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP)`

Code:

```
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex2f(-30.0, 30.0);
glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex2f(30.0, 30.0);
glColor3f(0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex2f(0.0, -30);
glEnd();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Corners aren't going to be so pretty, but otherwise `GL_LINE_LOOP` should work. Can you show us your code using `GL_LINE_LOOP` and the results you're getting?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have added code with results, now how i can get required color and width of triangle?

Comment: Hi, first of all, you are programming with the old opengl version. The new version doesn't use glBegin. I'm not sure if the old version has the glLineWidth command...

Answer (score 2):

I would change your code to this:

```cpp
glLineWidth(5.0); // this makes 5 pixel thick lines
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(-30.0, 30.0); glVertex2f( 30.0, 30.0);
glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f( 30.0, 30.0); glVertex2f(  0.0,-30.0);
glColor3f(0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(  0.0,-30.0); glVertex2f(-30.0, 30.0); 
glEnd();
glLineWidth(1.0); // return state to original conditions
```

So you should have thick lines and the coloring should not interpolate between lines ...

Answer (score 1):

To remove color gradients, you have at least two options:

- You could call `glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);` before rendering the triangle.
- You could use `GL_LINES`, like so:

  ```
  glBegin(GL_LINES);
  glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
  glVertex2f(-30.0, 30.0);
  glVertex2f(30.0, 30.0);
  glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
  glVertex2f(30.0, 30.0);
  glVertex2f(0.0, -30);
  glColor3f(0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
  glVertex2f(0.0, -30);
  glVertex2f(-30.0, 30.0);
  glEnd();
  ```

To increase line width, you could use `glLineWidth`.

But you'll see that ends of wide lines normally don't look as pretty and round as on your image. If that's a problem for you, you'll have to  draw the shape using lots of carefully placed `GL_TRIANGLES` instead.

Comment: heh looks like you beat me ... strange did not see your answer before ... Now I am deciding if to delete or not ... any suggestions?

Comment: if you add the `glLineWidth(5.0); ... glLineWidth(1.0);` to your code I will delete mine ...